Linux how to get lowest possible stack address
I want to embed a Google V8 (v6.8) in a C++ program. Since this program uses a lot of stack, I want to configure the V8 to use the entire available stack. To do this, I need the smallest permitted stack address that the V8 can use.
uint32_t *base;
// TODO: set `base` to lowest stack address
...
v8::Isolate::CreateParams createParams;
createParams.array_buffer_allocator =
    v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
createParams.constraints.set_stack_limit(base);

defaultIsolate = Isolate::New(createParams);
...

Now I have to determine the value for base under Linux. To do this, I tried reading /proc/self/maps. However, the segment read for the stack is always only 132k in size:
7fff03e18000-7fff03e39000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]

This seems to be independent of which stack limit is set. I also tried reading the limit using getrlimit() and reducing the highest address by the limit. But that then leads to a crash.
Can anyone tell me how else I can find out the lowest stack address under Linux?

It looks like you are confusing the native stack with the v8 stack, which has nothing to do with the native stack. Just pick a number.

The v8 stack uses the program's normal stack. The limit tells v8 where the stack is limited.

If you don't set a limit, wouldn't v8 use as much as it can then? And what is your code doing that requires so much stack-space? By default Linux gives 8 MiB of stack to each process, what are you doing that exceeds that (which it doesn't, if your mappings are true)?

I don't know much about V8, but V8 and your program should need stack space to call functions and store stack variables. If the V8 VM stack is really on native stack, then it must be inside a stack frame of a certain function call. So if you let it use up all stack space, no new function calls can be made and it's doomed to crash.

@RibomBalt No. It shares the same stack. It allocates memory from stack if needed. But it needs a limit up which address the stack is allocate. If you reach this limit a Maximum call stack size exceeded exception (Java Script) is thrown. The V8 needs the limit of the stack to see if it can put anything more on the stack.

@Someprogrammerdude No. It limits its stack to an limited amount of memory. If the main program has already used a lot of stack, then a function call to a JavaScript function ends in an exception. Even if there was still enough stack available.

The address is irrelevant because it is virtual memory. But the stack has a size limit. See here on how to inspect and change it. And if you launch additional threads, look here

@Homer512 The JavaScript stack uses the C++ stack. To avoid everything ending in a seg. fault, V8 has an address up to which it uses the stack. This is a fixed value that works regardless of ulimit. If you set the stack too small, it simply crashes. If you increase the stack size, this has no effect on the stack of the JavaScript. The stack is only used up to the V8 limit. If I call JavaScript from C++, the V8 stack is reduced by the amount that the C++ program is using at that time. If the amount is already larger than the V8 stack, then JavaScript has no stack and an exception is thrown.

Ah, understood. The stack size mapping for the main thread (not other POSIX threads) will dynamically grow up to the limit. You can verify that with a large alloca, followed by a memset, looking at /proc/self/maps before and after the allocation + memset. If I read the API correctly, you set the value beyond which the stack must not grow. Because it's a stack and grows to smaller addresses, that would be the end address from /proc/self/maps minus the ulimit.  There is probably a better API for that

@Homer512 Yes. end_address - start-address is only 132k.  I tried end_address - ulimit, but it crashed. I also tried end_address - ulimit + 1MB and it seems to work, but i don't know if it will always work.

@MarcusHampel The limit reported by pthreads in my answer below is exactly 12 kiB smaller than what ulimit reports, which explains the crash. I don't know what's up with that. Maybe some sort of guard page?

@Homer512 In my test case it was exactly the same address as calculated from end_address - ulimit before.

The address range that you read from /proc/self/maps is misleading because the memory mapping for the stack of the main thread grows dynamically. The stacks for other threads do not grow, as far as I understand it.
Here is a Linux-specific way to retrieve the full range of the stack:
#define _GNU_SOURCE
/* required for _np functions */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(void)
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    void* stackaddr;
    size_t stacksize;
    if(pthread_getattr_np(pthread_self(), &attr))
        return 1;
    if(pthread_attr_getstack(&attr, &stackaddr, &stacksize))
        return 1;
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
}

The stackaddr is the lowest possible stack address. Because the stack grows towards lower addresses, this should be the end address for your stack limit parameter. I have verified that you can write to that address and that this will grow the stack size mapping to 8 MiB or whatever your process limit is.

It works in a way. It is the same address that I already got with end_address - ulimit. I tested it even more intensively: I have to stay at least 3k above this address so that V8 doesn't crash when I do an endless recursion.
Thanks for the help. In any case, it is a better method of determining the end of the stack.

@MarcusHampel The code to determine the stack (line 76ff) actually parses /proc/self/maps but does some corrections. I'm not sure why you need to reserve extra space but I'm also not sure how v8 determines how much stack it needs. It can't control every standard function it might call and which might use stack memory. And it certainly can't control the signal handlers (which use the same stack). So it makes some sense that you need to keep a reserve
